# Column Menu Templates and Nested Menu in AngularJS ui-grid

Tags: angularjs

How to implement below Filter with angularJS ui-grid

i want the filter to be like this image - click on this link to see the image...[image]

I need to add this filter to all the column headers.

Comment: Are you sure it's Angular and not AngularJS?

Comment: no my bad i want to impliment in angularJS only. @Ploppy

Comment: Please change the tag to AngularJS instead of Angular in order to get the appropriate answers.